# how to read th r,g,b values of an quantized image

Tags: matlab

i have quantized an image to 64 colors using [IND,map]=rgb2ind(RGB,64)
my question is,how can i read the red pixel intensity,green pixel intensity and blue pixel intesity of each pixel from the quantized image.
thanking you
dev